# Vanity Url ID issue

Tags: php, vanity-url

I am trying to do vanity url.

I want this http://mydomain.com/series/profile.php?profile_id=751130015 to become something like this

http://mydomain.com/series/751130015

I've tried creating a new file '.htaccess' on the directory and add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?profile_id=$1
```

Yet, I am still getting an error when I try to acccess

http://mydomain.com/series/751130015

Am I missing anything?

The error I am getting is:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404

Comment: What is the error you are given? That's your first clue.

Comment: first off: _what_ error are you getting? Add that to your question. Second, if it is a generic error, check your error_logs for more information.

Comment: I've added the error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^series/([0-9]+)$ /series/profile.php?profile_id=$1 [L]
```

explanation:

anything that **starts (^)** with **"series"** then a **dash (/)** followed by **numbers ( ([0-9]+) ) - also remember these numbers as the first variable "$1"** and eventually **ending ($)** will be redirected to /series/profile.php?profile_id=**$1**

so http://mydomain.com/series/751130015

will be redirected to http://mydomain.com/series/profile.php?profile_id=751130015

**UPDATE: the other way around:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/series/profile\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^profile_id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/series/%1? [R=301,L]
```

explanation (first condition) if /series/profile.php is called with (second condition) parameters starting with "profile_id=" and is followed by numbers then do the rewrite like this: go to http://mydomain.com/series/ and add whatever the numbers were at the end and stop there **(?)** -we intentionally stop there to avoid query_string appended to rewrite result. inform the visitor that this is a PERMANENT REDIRECT with status 301. Then terminate the htaccess execution **(L)**

so http://mydomain.com/series/profile.php?profile_id=751130015 will redirect (R=301 - PERMANENT REDIRECT)  to http://mydomain.com/series/751130015

(you can use R=302 for temporary redirect)

Comment: i'm testing this and i see its working...??? just tested on [this online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: The original url is this one http://mydomain.com/series/profile.php?profile_id=751130015, and I want it to be redirected to http://mydomain.com/series/751130015. kinda opposite of what you are saying

Comment: I found the error. I just need to add the series on this url RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?profile_id=$1. Which becomes like this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ series/profile.php?profile_id=$1

Comment: without RewriteCond, the "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ series/profile.php?profile_id=$1" will redirect all your pages to the series/profile.php